# Image Scaling to fill div CSS

Tags: jquery, html, css

How would i go about scaling an image so that it stays in the same aspect ratio to fit inside a div 100 px by 100 px. But the added problem i guess you could say is that i only want to scale it up or down so that it just fills that height and width. For example if i have an image that is 51 px by 51 px it would scale it up to 102px by 102px. There as you can see it fill the entire div even though it has to overflow a bit. Ive tried all the max-width and stuff like that and if the answer were to be in jquery i would need a bit of an explanation as i dont know jquery.Thankyou in advance

Answer (score 2):

Do you have any code you could provide?

Give this a shot:

CSS:

```
#container {
  width: 102px;
  height: 102px;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  background: url(../images/your-image-goes-here.png) no-repeat 0 0;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="container">
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You would set the div width and height to the exact size and the image width and height to 100% e.g.

**CSS**

```
#container {
    width: 102px;
    height: 102px;
}
#image {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="container">
    <img id="image" src="random" />
</div>
```

Be careful with the image resolution though because if it's scaled up too much the quality will be poor.

Comment: Only works because the ratio is 1:1.

What happens if he has images with different ratios?

Comment: The aspect ratio will already have been set from the width and height of the container.

Answer (score 1):

You need the image div inside the imagewrapper.  The secret is in the padding-bottom, this is specifying a 2:1 ratio.  Experiment ;)

```
#imagewrapper {
    position: relative;
    padding-bottom: 50%;
    height: 0;
}

#image { 
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look on following link its a very comprehensive implementation about image stretching:

http://www.selbie.com/playground/aspectcorrect/aspectcorrect.htm

Open a page source in browser and go to aspectratio.js file there is just one function written which does everything you need.

i hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

**HTML**

```
<div class="frame">
  <!-- Image original size is 36x33 px -->
  <img src="http://www.clickworkforce.com/images/software/icon-jquery.jpg" alt="jQuery"/>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.frame {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}
```

**jQuery**

```
$(function() {

  var frm    = $('.frame'),
      frmImg = $('.frame img');

  frmImg.css({ height: frm.innerHeight(), width: frm.innerWidth() });

});
```

Take a look at [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mdesdev/aUdKH/)